# Run WordCount example map reduce on AWS EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I am trying to run the word count example on AWS EMR, however I am having a hard time deploying and running the jar on the cluster. Its a customized word count example, where I have used some JSON parsing. The input is in my S3 bucket. When I try to run my job on EMR cluster I am getting the error that main function was not found in my Mapper class. Everywhere on the internet, the code for the word count example map reduce job is like they have created, three class, one static mapper class that extend Mapper, then the reducer which extends Reducer, and then the main class which contains the job configuration, so I am not sure why I am seeing the error. I build my code using maven assembly plugin so as to wrap all the third party dependencies in my JAR. Here is my code that I have written

```
package com.amalwa.hadoop.MapReduce;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ETL{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: ETL <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "etl");
        job.setJarByClass(ETL.class);

        job.setMapperClass(JsonParserMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(JsonParserReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(TweetArray.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

    public static class JsonParserMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
        private Text mapperKey = null;
        private Text mapperValue = null;
        Date filterDate = getDate("Sun Apr 20 00:00:00 +0000 2014");

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String jsonString = value.toString();
            if(!jsonString.isEmpty()){
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Map<String, Object> tweetData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);
                Date timeStamp = getDate(tweetData.get("created_at").toString());
                if(timeStamp.after(filterDate)){
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap<String, Object> userData = (com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>) tweetData.get("user");
                    mapperKey = new Text(userData.get("id_str") + "~" + tweetData.get("created_at").toString());
                    mapperValue = new Text(tweetData.get("text").toString() + " tweetId = " + tweetData.get("id_str"));
                    context.write(mapperKey, mapperValue);
                }
            }
        }

        public Date getDate(String timeStamp){
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = simpleDateFormat.parse(timeStamp);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return date;
        }
    }

    public static class JsonParserReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, TweetArray> {
        private ArrayList<Text> tweetList = new ArrayList<Text>();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (Text val : values) {
                tweetList.add(new Text(val.toString()));
            }
            context.write(key, new TweetArray(Text.class, tweetList.toArray(new Text[tweetList.size()])));
        }
    }
}
```

please if someone can clarify this problem, it would be really nice. I have deployed this jar on my local machine on which I installed hadoop and it works fine, but when I set up my cluster using AWS and provide the streaming job with all the parameters it doesn't work. Here is a screen shot of my configuration:

[image]

```
The Mapper textbox is set to: java -classpath MapReduce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.amalwa.hadoop.MapReduce.JsonParserMapper
The Reducer textbox is set to: java -classpath MapReduce-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.amalwa.hadoop.MapReduce.JsonParserReducer
```

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 4):

You need to select custom jar step instead of streaming program.

Answer (score 0):

When you make the jar file (I usually do it using Eclipse or a custom gradle build), check if your main class is set to ETL. Apparently, that does not happen by default. Also check the Java version you are using on ur system. I think the aws emr works with upto java 7.